# sitecore Rich Text Editor is not working on IE9

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor, sitecore8

Sitecore Rich Text Editor will open Internet explorer 9  but If click accept button after typing something in Rich Text area, the text will disappear but the page does not close when you press the accept button.  If you do close it, then it has not saved the typing thing in Rich Text area.

I'm using Sitecore Version 8. How can I fix this issue.

I have added the  images 
1. this image shows a text in Rich Text Editor 
[Rich Text Editor with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYvmN.png)
2.This image shows  the text will disappear after clicking accept button but the page does not close.
[Rich Text value disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFPp5.png)

Comment: Any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: No, I didn't get any javascript errors in the console,

Comment: Anything in the logs ?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me in Sitecore 8 update-3 with IE9. Make sure compatibility mode is not turned on and also check the Browser Mode and Document Mode is set to IE9 (press F12 and check along the top of the console popup)

Comment: Listening to @jammykam and making this a comment instead of an answer.  Microsoft is [ending support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) for it in just over a month, so if it is only IE9 that has a problem, it's probably not worth the time to troubleshoot.  Have you tested other browsers?

Comment: I'm Using Sitecore 8 update-4 with IE9. but I still get same issue. if you have any idea please share with me.

Comment: @ArunaMahesh Did you check the compatibility mode as well as browser/document mode like I suggested?